# Built up string causing a syntax issue

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c# function that builds a string which in turn is used as a hyperlink to another page.  However, with some strings with single quotes it is causing a javascript error as shown here:

[image]

I'm calling the javascript function in the code behind as so

```
linkFullMatch.NavigateUrl = "javascript:showFullMatches(" + sb.ToString() + ")";
```

the javascript is on the aspx function as so:

```
<script>
function showFullMatches(url) {
    window.open(url, "_blank", "height=344,width=1100,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,left=580,top=194");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Any string that doesn't have a single quote in works fine and the page link opens as requested.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional layer of quote marks to make the `sb.ToString()` value an JS string. Adjust your call like:

```
linkFullMatch.NavigateUrl = "javascript:showFullMatches('" + sb.ToString() + "')";
```

Note the additional `'` marks.